# Calculate Symmetric Difference of intervals fast

Tags: algorithms

Is there a fast way in computational terms to check that  $A \bigtriangleup B \bigtriangleup C  = A \cup B \cup C $ if $A,B,C$ are intervals $[a,b]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
A\Delta B \Delta C = (A\cup B\cup C - A\cup B - A \cup C - B\cup C)\cup (A\cap B\cap C) 
$$
So $A\Delta B \Delta C = A\cup B\cup C$ if and only if
$$
  A\cap B = A \cap C = B\cap C= A\cap B\cap C
$$
Or equivalently,
$$
  A\cap B\subset C,\qquad A\cap C\subset B,\qquad B\cap C\subset A
$$